# How to open a popup which contain 2 portlet in 2 seperate tab in websphere portal server 6.1?

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

My requirement is :

There will be a link in a portal page, Upon clicking that link it will open up a popup, which contain 2 portlet in 2 seperate tab within that popup.

Answer (score 0):

which theme are you using on 6.1?  We did something similar in this case study
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0809_barnes/0809_barnes.html